# Objective C - Problems With TableView Check Box Using Sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm implementing a contact check-box feature in my UITableView by using the following code.

The problem I'm having is that, when checking off a couple of users and then scrolling up/down the table, users who should not be checked off are showing as checked, and vice versa.

I'm assuming it has something to do with an error in my cell creation, but I'm not quite sure what.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    ...

    self.checkedUsers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<self.allContacts.count; i++) {
        [self.checkedUsers insertObject:@"FALSE" atIndex:i];
    }

    ...
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SocietyContactCell";
     SocietyContactCell *cell = (SocietyContactCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

          if (cell == nil) {        
          NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SocietyContactCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
          }

     BOOL checked =  [[self.checkedUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
     UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedContact.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedContact.png"];

     [cell.checkButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [cell.checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)buttonPressedAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    int row = button.tag;

    BOOL checked = [[self.checkedUsers objectAtIndex:row] boolValue];
    [self.checkedUsers removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    [self.checkedUsers insertObject:(checked) ? @"FALSE":@"TRUE" atIndex:row];

    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedContact.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedContact.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

**EDIT**: I now realize the issue is likely coming from my use of sections in this TableView. The contacts are sorted into alphabetized sections, which is messing up my tags.

How would I tackle this problem using sections?

Comment: Where do you initialize the itsToDoChecked array ?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff sorry, i've edited the code

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is retention of the status of checkmark in a cell. Since the table cells are reused on scrolling, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is called again and the value of the check mark is not set again there.

You will have to make a global array which will store the status of the checkmark for each `indexPath`. Then you can set the status of the checkmark button `checked/unchecked` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Add the following code snippet along with the code show:

```
 [cell.checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [cell.checkButton setTag:indexPath.row];
```

Also, replace these lines:

```
[self.checkedUsers removeObjectAtIndex:row];
[self.checkedUsers insertObject:(checked) ? @"FALSE":@"TRUE" atIndex:row];
```

with this:

```
[self.checkedUsers replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:checked ? @"TRUE" : @"FALSE"];
```

Comment: i'm confused...isn't my code in cellForRowAtIndex path correctly checking the checkedUsers array to determine the status of checkmark?

Comment: I just logged out the tag and I now realize that the issue is coming likely because I am using sections...the contacts are put into alphabetical sections. any suggestions on how to deal with this problem using sections?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are setting button.tag every time in cellForRowAtIndexPath:, so the action method might be updating the wrong row in your self.checkedUsers array, although the action method independently updates the cell's image correctly at the moment.  When you scroll up and down however, the display will go back to the state in the self.checkedUsers array.

You probably need a line like:

```
cell.checkButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.

Secondly, your action method is getting the state on self.itsToDoChecked, and then updating a self.checkedUsers array, when it appears it should be acting on the same array (simply reversing the state of the given row index).  Not sure if that is just an example code typo or something significant.

Edit: It's also possible there is state in the cell subclass causing issues; hard to be sure.  You want to implement -prepareForReuse in that class (and always call super) to reset any state to initial values.

Comment: adding the tag doesn't seem to solve the issue...and yes, that was a typo. I've edited

Comment: So if you log out the tag in the action method, is it always the right one?

Comment: I just logged out the tag and I now realize that the issue is coming likely because I am using sections...the contacts are put into alphabetical sections. any suggestions on how to deal with this problem using sections?

Comment: There could be a few ways.  You could store the whole NSIndexPath on the button as an associated object.  You could walk through the button's superviews until you find a UITableViewCell, then use UITableView's -indexPathForCell: method to get the index path.  You could make the tag a calculation -- tag == indexPath.section * 1000 + indexPath.row; then in the method you could get section = tag / 1000  and row = tag % 1000.

Comment: In all cases though your checkedUsers array is flat; that would need to change to be an array of arrays (one top-level array per section, and the subarrays are all the rows in that section) and update accesses accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In your SocietyContactCell Class add the following Method:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [self.checkButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```